# Access parent's Ref in child component on child mount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following Parent/Child components. I need to scroll to top as soon as the Child component is initially rendered.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Child from "./Child";

class Parent extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div ref={topDiv => {
          this.topDiv = topDiv;
        }}/>
        <Child
          topDiv={this.topDiv}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Parent;
```

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Child extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.scrollToTop();
  }

  // componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextContext) {
  //   nextProps.topDiv.scrollIntoView();
  // }

  scrollToTop() {
    this.props.topDiv.scrollIntoView();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{height: '500rem'}}>
        Long Child
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```

Using this, I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of undefined

I think this is because when `componentDidMount` is called, the props have not been received yet, so `topDiv` is null/undefined.

If I use `componentWillReceiveProps` as shown in the commented part, it works fine. But I can't use it because:
1. It is deprecated.
2. I think it will be called every time props are received. So I guess I'll need to keep a variable to know if it's the first time props are being received?

I can't use `componentDidUpdate` because the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) says "*This method is not called for the initial render.*".

**How to do something when props are received the first time after a component is rendered?**

Comment: You should try it after it occurs. Like `{ this.topDiv && <Child topDiv={this.topDiv} /> }`

Comment: turn `scrollToTop` into an arrow function and it will work; or do what Simran suggests in his answer. there are benefits and costs of doing each.

Comment: @Derek I tried arrow and constructor, neither worked. Same error. :(

Comment: You can see how to change react component's state

Comment: @hongtumiao I know how to set state. How does it help with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props are definitely supposed to be available in `componentDidMount`.

This seems like it could be stemming from some messiness from the React lifecycle.

In your parent, you're providing a ref callback in a render at approximately the same time you're mounting `Child`.  According to the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

> React will call the ref callback with the DOM element when the component mounts, and call it with null when it unmounts. Refs are guaranteed to be up-to-date before componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate fires.

However, `componentDidMount` of the children will fire before the `componentDidMount` of their parent, so this guarantee doesn't mean `Parent`'s `this.topDiv` will be defined before `Child` calls `componentDidMount`. (And, thinking on it further, it definitely doesn't guarantee that it'll be defined before being provided to `Child` as a prop.)

In your parent, you could maybe try something like

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ divSet: true });
}

render() {
    let child = null;
    if (this.state.divSet) {
        child = <Child topDiv={this.topDiv} />
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <div ref={topDiv => {
          this.topDiv = topDiv;
        }}/>
        {child}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

This will guarantee that your ref is set before `Child` mounts.  The `setState` is specifically used to force the parent to rerender when the ref is set.

Comment: it's looping infinitely on `this.setState({ divSet: true });` - Maximum update depth exceeded.

Comment: Ah, my bad.  Try putting `this.setState({ divSet: true })` in the parent's `ComponentDidMount` instead.  I can't mess around on a CodePen right now, but you see what I'm getting at right?  You want to prevent `Child` from rendering before `this.topDiv` is defined.

Comment: It's not throwing that error now, but when I tested the scroll by moving the `topDiv` to the bottom, it didn't scroll to it. Perhaps I missed something, I'll think of a way to test it properly. On a separate note, I moved the scrolling logic to the parent, which is better because the parent should be responsible for scrolling to its own div, not the child, and it works fine. I'll accept this answer anyway after I do some more testing. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is by definition, impossible! When you say

> I need to scroll to top as soon as the Child component is initially
>   rendered.

you mean the Parent's top right?

But the key detail here is

> As soon as your child has completed rendering, your parent has not yet
>   been rendered! There is no top to scroll to Yet!

---

**Life Cycles of a component**

This is the typical lifecycle flow of a component

1. constructor()
2. componentWillMount()
3. render()
4. componentDidMount()

When it comes to a parent child relationship it will be

1. [Parent]constructor()
2. [Parent]componentWillMount()
3. [Parent]render()

   1. [Child]constructor()
   2. [Child]componentWillMount()
   3. [Child]render()
   4. [Child]componentDidMount() - Parent does not exist yet
4. [Parent]componentDidMount()

Also a small note on the newly added lifecycle method in place of componenWillRecieveProps which is

> **getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state)**
>
> getDerivedStateFromProps is invoked right before calling the render
>   method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates. It should
>   return an object to update the state, or null to update nothing.

---

> So your best bet is to call the scroll top within your paren't
>   component componentDidMount where you will have access to it's ref.

If you are still determined to do this in the child component, you will have to use **getDerivedStateFromProps** in combination with a flag in state to detect whether you have already scrolled to the top at least once. This can be a bit efficient and dirty overall.

Check [here](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) for a cool flow diagram of component lifecycle for clarity!

Comment: Thanks, upvoted. I moved the scrolling logic to the parent, which is better because the parent should be responsible for scrolling to its own div, not the child, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Bind `this.scrollToTop` to your class component in the `constructor`:

```
class Child extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.scrollToTop = this.scrollToTop.bind(this);
  }
  ...rest of your component code
```

Comment: doesn't work.. I even added the call to `super` - `constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.scrollToTop = this.scrollToTop.bind(this);
  }`